# Just finished the Martian Chronicles. "The Off Season" left me baffled

Tags: ray-bradbury, the-martian-chronicles

1. Sam Parkhill is obviously a character you love to hate, but I was left baffled when the Martians gave him land deeds to half of Mars, especially after he shot one of them.  Why would they do that?  Were the deeds real?  Why did they chase down Sam so vigorously to talk to him specifically?
2. I assume not, but did Sam return to Earth in the end?
3. The 150 Martians that give Same the deeds... it seems like they are still alive at the end of the book with no mention.  Perhaps at the end of the book there are still quite a few humans and martians left on the planet?  If so, was anything else written to talk about all of the people still on Mars, and maybe they all found a way to live in peace in the end?

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Literature! Looks like you have some interesting questions here, but a couple of pieces of advice ... 1) Please only ask one question per question. If your three numbered points aren't somehow interconnected (i.e. answering one of them would involve answering the others too), then they should be posted as separate questions. 2) Questions should be, at least to some extent, objectively answerable. It's OK to ask something that has no single true answer and can depend on different readings of the text, but "I'm curious what other people think" is too *discussiony* to work well on SE.

Comment: 2. Return to Earth? Didn't Sam see the Earth blow up at one point in the story?

Comment: I think everyone went back after the partial blow up.  I think that was the trigger.  @user14111

Answer (score 1):

The Martians knew that the big war was about to start and this would be the end to Sam's dreams so why not gently build him up before letting him fall? After all, revenge is a dish best served cold.

Another theory - why would everyone rush back from a safe place to an earth that is being destroyed by nuclear war? Nostalgia, ties, duty to help the country etc. yes all true motivations in this case - but maybe the remaining telepathic Martians strengthened those motivations just enough to drive most of the humans off the planet? And then play an ironic "joke" on their biggest tormenter.